# Multiple Spring Cloud GCP libraries in single project causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud

If I use a single Spring Cloud GCP library e.g. `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql:1.1.1.RELEASE")` and the property: `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key=` for credentials... everything works fine.

But if I also want to say add pub/sub to my project via: `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.1.3.RELEASE")` then I get the exception below.

I have tried:

1. Using different Java versions 11 and 12
2. Different Spring Cloud GCP libraries as the "second" library  `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter:1.1.3.RELEASE")` and `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging:1.1.3.RELEASE")`
3. Using `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location` instead of `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key`
4. Use admin service account to make sure it's not a IAM role issue.

`implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter:1.1.3.RELEASE")` and `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging:1.1.3.RELEASE")`

As soon as I include more than one of these Spring Cloud GCP libraries, the same `SocketFactory` error comes up without fail. From the docs, it should work fine. The second library should just use the same credentials.

If I revert back to a single library then it works fine.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Factory method 'cloudSqlDataSourceProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/sql/core/CoreSocketFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 171 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/sql/core/CoreSocketFactory
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration.cloudSqlDataSourceProperties(GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java:209) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f5495da.CGLIB$cloudSqlDataSourceProperties$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f5495da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$58c2377.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$CloudSqlDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f5495da.cloudSqlDataSourceProperties(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 172 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 183 common frames omitted
```

I have also created a Github Issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different versions of the libraries were used due to copy-paste import from Maven Central without checking versions.

Versions used included `1.1.1.RELEASE` and `1.1.3.RELEASE`. Only one of those release numbers should have been used at a time.

Refactored code to remove posibility of this error:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql:$springCloudGCPVersion")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:$springCloudGCPVersion")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:$springCloudGCPVersion")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter:$springCloudGCPVersion")
```

Comment: It's also better to use the BOM. In fact, when using w/ Spring Boot, it should just import the Spring Cloud BOM. I recommend generating the initial project from start.spring.io. Which produces a gradle build like this: https://gist.github.com/saturnism/7114a473866aa46fdec8405589d579de